# Verb/subject agreement "Irregularities with nutritional status has/have"

Tags: verb-agreement

I am having some trouble with the sentence:

"Irregularities with nutritional status ***has*** been recognised as dangerous."

According to https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/subject_verb_agreement.html , this sentence is incorrect, but MS Word's grammar check and my language intuition both say "have" sounds funny.

In my head, I read "Irregularities with nutritional status" as "altered nutritional status" and thus is one thing.

Is there any logic to this?

Edit: I can create more sentences that, to me, would have the same weirdness to it, like:

*Multiple suicide ideations has been seen by therapists as a warning sign.*

*English difficulties has become a problem of this student.*

I believe there is a hidden [Having], but I don't know if that plays any role.

Comment: The correct logic to use is to drop the prepositional phrase after the headnoun and see how it reads. "[These] [i]rregularities **have** been recognised as dangerous."

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth that is a good rule of thumb. I would add further to that and say that actually the way the subject phrase is formed is important. In this case the order of the nouns is probably incorrect along with a few other problems in that sentence. I mean grammatically, I just don't think that the sentence makes sense.

Comment: I think my brain is just shorting. I can understand the grammar behind it, but there is something about the meaning that seems to change. I will just rephrase this.

Comment: No. English difficulties ***have*** become a problem ***for*** this student. A verb must agree with its subject.  Always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context will determine whether "Irregularities with nutritional status" is singular or plural.

As a compound noun phrase, it can have a singular concord when used as the name/title/label of a condition/state and thus a category. Effectively, it is the same as "All accidents are worrying but accidents with a fatal outcome is a category of concern."

On the other hand, if "with nutritional status" is merely a modifying phrase that distinguishes its noun from another set of irregularities, e.g. Irregularities with the skin, then it has a plural concord.

Comment: Opinions with red flags is optional? Really?

Answer (score 0):

**The bit you know:**

I think the logic in English language is that where the subject noun is plural, there needs to be plural verb form. Modifications or alterations to the noun plural do not change the plurality of the verb.

So for example:

```
Red cars are considered by some drivers to be faster.
```

In this sentence, we couldn't say "is considered to by some drivers to be faster".

If we then said:

```
Cars with red paint are considered by some to be faster.
```

Again, the use of a singular verb form "is" would be inappropriate here.

In the first example, we used an adjective to modify the description of the subject. In the second sentence, we use a preposition to modify the meaning.

In neither case do we modify the plurality.

**The bit that's probably wrong:**

In this case, the subject of the sentence is actually the nutritional status, not the irregularities. It doesn't make semantic sense any other way even though "syntactically" it makes sense. This is because irregularities cannot have a nutritional status - it just doesn't make sense.

It does make me wonder actually if the sentence would be better worded as:

```
Nutritional information with irregularities or inaccuracies has been found to be dangerous.
```

So I think in answer to your question, the order of the nouns in the sentence could be important, and in this case the order of the nouns are probably incorrect, which is why you are seeing this inconsistency.

Adding what Edwin said, because it's actually really useful:

*The correct logic to use is to drop the prepositional phrase after the headnoun and see how it reads. "[These] [i]rregularities have been recognised as dangerous." – Edwin Ashworth*

But again, it's contingent on the sentence subject being first, before the prepositional phrase.